# Android setting font in text view

Tags: java, android

Hi I am trying to change the font style of a `TextView`. I know how to change it, I have done this before I am using the following code.

```
public class Main_Activity extends ListActivity {
    Typeface myNewFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/bediz__.ttf");
    private CustomListAdapter adap;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    adap = new CustomListAdapter(this);
    setListAdapter(adap);
}
    public static class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements
        Filterable {
           public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        textView.setText(prayers[position]);
        holder.textLine.setTypeface(myNewFace);
           }
}
```

Some of the code I skipped because there is no need, by the way when I access `myNewFace` in `getView()` it ask me to make it `static`, when I make it `static` like this

```
static Typeface myNewFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/bediz__.ttf");
```

It gives me the following error

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getAssets() from the type ContextWrapper
```

I dont know what to do, I have done this work several times before but now I dont know why it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to just do this

```
static Typeface myNewFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/bediz__.ttf");
```

where context should be the context of the class which is makinng call to the adapter.

Comment: Since this is a static initializer, there is no `context` object to work with.

Comment: thank you so much, it worked. I will accept your answer after 7 mins

Comment: @user1420026 good to know it worked for you. you can upvote too if you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have declared your `inner class` as `static;` making your `inner class` a top-level nested class and no longer a member `nested class;` therefore, you cannot access any longer any `non-static member` of the `outer class` without first going through a reference to an instantiated object.

For a `non-static inner class`, a (hidden) reference to the outer object is always passed on when an `object` for an `inner class` is created; therefore giving access to all the members of the outer `object/class`.  For a `static inner class`, this reference is not passed.

As to your sample, you could use the reference to the outer object that you are explicitly passing along when creating a new CustomListAdapter object: "`adap = new CustomListAdapter(this);`" but a better solution is probably to drop this static keyword from the inner class definition.  You won't need to pass a reference to the outer object anymore either.